# StatusChanges returns the status before the AsyncValidators is called

Tags: angular, forms, controls, customvalidator

With statusChanges I check for errors. I output the resulting array of errors in the html template.
For the input field, I use an asynchronous validator. When entering text in the input field or losing focus, first statusChanges returns the status and then the asynchronous validator is called and again statusChanges returns the status. The call order will be

- 1.statusChanges
- 2.AsyncValidator
- 3.statusChanges

If I enter an already existing name in the input field, the error is displayed correctly. The problem is that if the field loses focus, the order I wrote above is executed again. The first time is called statusChanges, I get an empty array. Thus, the error that is already displayed under the field will flicker.

- 1.statusChanges // empty array
- 2.AsyncValidator
- 3.statusChanges // array with error

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  this.control.statusChanges.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(() => {
    const newErrors: string[] = Object.keys(this.control.errors || []).map((error) => {
          if (this.control.errors[error].message) {
            return this.control.errors[error].message;
          }

          return this.getDefaultError(error as DefaultValidationError); //return defaul error text
        });
        this.messages = newErrors; //array with errors text string[]
  });

**HTML template **
  <mat-error *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <span [innerHTML]="message"></span>
  </mat-error>
```

[image]

How can this problem be avoided?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; you want to ignore `PENDING` statuses in your Observable.

I'm going to try to answer your question and fix some major issues here at the same time.

- Don't subscribe to Observables in `ngOnChanges`. You're creating as many subscriptions as there are change detection cycles. Big no-no: subscribe once in `ngOnInit`, if at all
- Don't put logic in `subscribe` callbacks: operators are preferable.
- Where possible, don't subscribe in your TS. Using the `async` pipe is much cleaner.
- Use string interpolation, not `innerHTML`.

All of this leading to something along these lines:

```js
messages$: Observable<string[]>;
ngOnInit() {
  this.messages$ = this.control.statusChanges.pipe(
    filter(status => status === 'VALID' || status === 'INVALID'),
    map(() => Object.keys(this.control.errors || []).map((error) => {
        // do your thing
      });
    )
  );
}
```

```html
<mat-error *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
  <span>{{ message }}</span>
</mat-error>
```

Comment: I am using a custom input which is implemented from ControlValueAccessor. This input validates its value after losing focus. My form submit button still has a flickering effect because I'm using form.controls.general.invalid for disabled

[disabled]="form.controls.general.invalid"


[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UVUQ1a5O9Jgm56nTSL0Mwftsh9Ndd0Hn/view?usp=share_link)

How can this flickering effect be avoided?

Comment: Try changing to !valid rather than invalid in your disabled binding. Currently, a “pending” status enables your button, hence the flash.